# Setting up feature vectors

Tags: clustering, categorical-data, svm, feature-selection

I am working on a classification project and I want to use SVM's and/or Clustering Algs.

What I am having trouble with is deciding how to set up my feature vectors. I have already decided what my features will be and I have already taken into account things like correlation and overfitting.

Some of my features are categorical (region, gender, occupation...) and some are numeric (age, income,...) I would like to use some if not all of these. But I am not sure how to quantify the features in such a way that is accurate and will not create noise.

(One thing I thought to do was for each categorical variable, say gender, calculate something relevant that has to do with the variable (say probability of default given that you are of some gender). The idea is to find something highly correlated with the categorical variable and use that value instead.)

Id appreciate any tips or references!

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a classifier which is nonparametric like random forest or a C5 tree. As a first exercise throw all those features associated to your labeled vector and train a model. Evaluate the performance. Both of these have no assumptions on the features they are built upon, they won't mind if the features are correlated or what their nature is (categorical, ordinal, continuous). They will even kind of perform variable selection on the fly so they are resistant against the curse of dimensionality. If you provide some sample data I'll help you mockup a working prediction example in R.

Comment: Thanks! Let me see if I can share some of this data (is there an email I could send it to?), there may be NDA issues. But in the meantime I will certainly look into random forest/c5 Trees. Follow up question: are SVM's not suited for this kind of analysis? Do they no respond well to categorical values? Is it just too much effort in practice?

Comment: It's possible to use them but not so directly as in, for example, random forest where absolutely no data preprocessing of the feature variables is needed. In fact they are totally inmune to monotonic transformations of continuous features. That being said SVM can perform very well but need a little knowledge on how to tune them, they have more complicated hyperparameters. Random forest is a very easy way to get acceptable results so I would go for this first.